How to solve camera init problem in esp32-cam and micropython
i wrote this code to my esp32-cam with micropython but when i run it, it shows me error below and doesn't take picture, at first it showed this error and start rebooting and restarting, i plogged in the 5v and it did not restart, but now i have this error:
import machine
from machine import Pin
import camera
import time

flash = Pin(4, Pin.OUT)
uos.mount(machine.SDCard(), "/sd")  #mount the SD card
camera.init()
camera.quality(10)
camera.framesize(9)
count = 0
while True:
    if count == 2200:
        print("Completed")
        break
    flash.value(1)
    pic = camera.capture()
    flash.value(0)
    file = open("/sd/pics/"+str(count)+".jpg", "wb")
    file.write(pic)
    file.close()
    print(count, " done")
    count += 1
    time.sleep(1)

print("done")



I (462) psram: This chip is ESP32-D0WD
I (462) spiram: Found 16MBit SPI RAM device
I (462) spiram: SPI RAM mode: flash 40m sram 40m
I (465) spiram: PSRAM initialized, cache is in low/high (2-core) mode.
I (472) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.
I (476) cpu_start: Application information:
I (481) cpu_start: Compile time:     Dec 13 2019 08:15:03
I (487) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256:  0000000000000000...
I (493) cpu_start: ESP-IDF:          v3.3
I (498) cpu_start: Starting app cpu, entry point is 0x40083830
I (490) cpu_start: App cpu up.
I (946) spiram: SPI SRAM memory test OK
I (946) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
I (947) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 00001920 (6 KiB): DRAM
I (953) heap_init: At 3FFBAC10 len 000253F0 (148 KiB): DRAM
I (959) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM
I (965) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM
I (972) heap_init: At 40094998 len 0000B668 (45 KiB): IRAM
I (978) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code
I (983) spiram: Adding pool of 2048K of external SPI memory to heap allocator
I (109) cpu_start: Chip Revision: 2
W (110) cpu_start: Chip revision is higher than the one configured in menuconfig. Suggest to upgrade it.
I (113) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.
I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
I (123) spiram: Reserving pool of 32K of internal memory for DMA/internal allocations
I (153) main: Allocated 767K for micropython heap at 0x3f940020
I (293) sccb: pin_sda 26 pin_scl 27

I (293) gpio: GPIO[32]| InputEn: 0| OutputEn: 1| OpenDrain: 0| Pullup: 0| Pulldown: 0| Intr:0 
E (353) camera: Detected camera not supported.
E (353) camera: Camera probe failed with error 0x20004
E (353) camera: Camera Init Failed
E (353) camera: Quality Failed
E (363) camera: Framesize Failed
E (363) camera: Camera Capture Failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
TypeError: object with buffer protocol required

I asked chatgpt but it doesn't work. please help

What version of MicroPython are you using?

file.write(pic) expects bytes. Find out what datatype "pic" is, and how to convert it to bytes.
